# Datetime python script not outputting correct hour, minute, and second

Tags: python, datetime, python-3.x

I have the following code:

```
import datetime
Today = datetime.date.today()
print (Today.strftime("%m/%d/%Y-%H:%M:%S"))
```

And get the output `11/28/2015-00:00:00`. How do I make it display the correct hour, minute, and second instead of just zeros?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [`datetime.datetime.now()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.now) instead of [`datetime.date.today()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.today):

```
In [8]: today = datetime.datetime.now()

In [9]: print (today.strftime("%m/%d/%Y-%H:%M:%S"))
11/29/2015-10:27:32
```